# Blender 2.8 emmiter particle animation

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine

I was wondering if anyone managed to animate particles in blender 2.8(eevee).
I can render each image manually fine but If I hit animation button the application crashes.

And I was thinking. 
Incase no one managed to achieve particle animation yet without crashing,

The solution might be to create a script that renders the frame using render (image) button then switch one frame then render the frame and so on.
Because when I do it manually it doesn't crash. 
But hitting the render button 500 times is tedious at best.

Maybe one of our lovely programmers can do that for us.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about experimental development software

Comment: Can't vote on that, but yes, experimental software. Blender 2.8 isn't even in beta yet.

Comment: Why?I know it's experimental but at least provide a solution or don't create unnecessary comments. Btw I solved the problem, I'll post it so I can be of a help to someone unlike you two. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I have found my answer. 
1. Close the 3d view port. 
Replace it with a time line or anything. 
Apperantly eevee doesn't like animating while the viewport is open. (perhaps because the viewport updates too?)(not confirmed theory)

2.Delete any files that has the same naming scheme as blenders in the destination

3. Save the blend.
4. Reset the time line (shift+left arrow key)
5. Use a lower viewport and rendering samples. I lowered the rendering samples from 512 to 256 and it worked.
6. Run the simulation at least once using( alt+a)

   Restart eevee if you still get crashes,but save the file before to not lose changes and remember to run the simulation once.

You can hit animation button now with no issues.